# Bathtub spout feed unusually short

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, spout

I took off a bathtub wall spout fitting the other day and was surprised to find that the feed pipe that goes along the inside of the faucet piece was way shorter than I was expecting.  This really spoiled my day as I was hoping in the not too distant future to replace the entirety of the tub and surround with one of those one-piece inserts, specifically so that I would not have to pull out the tub, redo the walls, etc etc.  (edit: this is just an example.  The question remains even if I wanted only to keep everything the same and just replace the tub spout, which, unsurprisingly, is not as secure as it ought to be.)

Are their any elegant ways to lengthen the pipe?  It doesn't look like a sleeve fitting would be possible.  But that means I have to open up the wall...and then, presumably, find a way to replace just that pipe, without having to rebuild the entire fitting it connects to.  Which doesn't feel possible.

What techniques have others used?

Comment: What material is the pipe made from?

Comment: Do you have access to the plumbing from the other side of the wall?

Comment: "Replace the tub with" would involve pulling it out to put in a one-peice tub insert, assuming you could maneuver that through the house into your bathroom. But you say "specifically so I would not have to pull out the tub." Are you thinking one of those "reline your tub" products? I looked at them and found them to be a very high cost yet extremely cheap (look, wear, feel) product, from what I could see. There were also many complaints about poor plumbing practices by the installers (and no guarantee on whatever plumbing they did - just the on the chintzy liner itself.)

Comment: The horizontal tube going into the external spigot can be connected to the mixing valve in several ways. In the 50-year-old plumbing in my neighborhood this is a 1/2" diameter hard copper tube sweated into a 90 deg "L" . The end the spigot attaches to has a sweated on adapter--female tubing to male NPT (threaded). The spigot screws on. There are other ways to seal the spigot. How was your existing spigot attached? Depending on the material of the tubing feeding the spigot the pipe can easily be lengthened. What is the material of the tubing?

Comment: What kind of mixing valve do you have--two knob with diverter or single lever mixing valve?

Comment: You almost certainly would NOT have to open up the wall to lengthen this tube.

Comment: The difficulty or even the impossibility of maneuvering a single piece tub-shower into a finished bathroom has led to good retrofit units which come in several pieces. If you have 36" wide door into the bathroom, you might be able to get a single unit in through the door, but the hallway outside would have to be especially spacious to allow manipulating the unit through the door.

Comment: I edited the question to make the spout pipe issue the focus, not the tub liner.  The spout pipe is copper.  Judging from the other bathroom in the house, the pipe is probably on a descender from a central mixing valve controlled by two taps higher up the wall, with a riser coming out of that for the shower head.  So H+C feeds in and mixed feeds out.  All I see is the pipe disappearing into a hole in the tile.  No access from the back side either.